# how should I train a model with transformed parameters

Tags: regression

Lets say that we have the following model:

$y = sigmoid(w1)*x1 + w2*x3 + w3*x3$

and we would like to fit it in a dataset $(xn, yn)$. How can we do this? (e.g using gradient descent? Also, what could be the error function?

Same question for model $y = sigmoid(w11, w12)*x1 + w2*x3 + w3*x3$

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what `sigmoid(w11,w12)` should mean.

Comment: You could just use gradient descent to estimate `sigmoid(w1)`, then recover `w1` by inverting the sigmoid, provided the learned parameter is in [0,1]. Or do gradient descent directly, incorporating the derivative of the sigmoid with the Chain Rule?  Any reason these won't work, or would be suboptimal?

Comment: Yes you are right to ask what $ sigmoid (w11, w11) $ is. What I meant is $ g(w1, w2) $, instead of $ sigmoid (w1) $